# ASP ReportViewer displays with large show/hide parameters bar

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

Have a goofy issue that I can't seem to shake.

I am using the ReportViewer 11 (FROM VS2012) in my ASP page and when it displays it has a huge show/hide parameters bar.  I have fuddled with the height/width parameters but always the same. (The same meaning, even if i make the report small or large, the bar is proportionally large)

```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="1000px"  ProcessingMode="Remote" >  
        <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="http://XXXXXXXXX/reportserver" /> 
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Since I am a newbie I can't post the picture, so here is a link:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/dighazuse/9935229563

Thank you
DigHazuse

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

To hide the "Show / Hide parameters" Button:

```
ShowPromptAreaButton="false"
```

To show the Parameters area collapsed on startup:

```
PromptAreaCollapsed="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

On your page with the ReportViewer.. click on the ReportViewer then check your properties. There are a few properties you can mess with. There should be a ShowParameterPrompt and a few other options you may be able to set to true, or set to false. I would try to turn the ShowParameterPrompt to false and see if that fixes your issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response, Humpy.  It does look ok if I hide the parameters, but was hoping to not have to do that as this is part of a drop down of several reports, so I'd rather not have to build/pass the parameters in code.  DigHazuse